# shader MAD optimization and precision issues

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glsl, precision

I have problems with MAD optimization and numbers close to infinity/float border on OpenGL ES based hardware.

What  I'm trying to do:

```
vec2 k = d/l;         // VERYY BIG number 10^6 -10^8, but still ok by itself

//vertex.w = 0 or 1
res += k * (1.0 - vertex.w);  // enable/disable by !vertex.w This form is ok
//res += k - k *vertex.w;     // but this is not (I think it becomes NaN, cuz I don't see a thing)
```

What is most intresting (and make me to struggle for a long time with this) it's work ok on desktop hardware.

So... Is this ok, a normal behavior, or am I missing something?

Comment: What hardware do you use? This can be caused by lack of float precision.

Comment: @keaukraine - I encounter this issue on Android

Comment: What GPU does it have? They are all very different and have different bugs in both hardware and OpenGL drivers.

Comment: @keaukraine - Qualcomm 200

Comment: do you have some line like this `precision mediump float;` at top of your shader?

Comment: @SAKrisT - no, I don't

Comment: so, you using OpenGL ES without specifying the precision's? If yes, that may your problem.

Comment: I specify only attributes/uniforms (which is required). And I tested it with highp/mediump precision qualifier too.

Answer (score 0):

this could depend on the float resolution of your GPU (is should be an Adreno 203?).

Most of the time it depends on an optimization performed by the driver on the float numbers which (AFAIK) strips part of the mantissa of the float number (hope to have said this well) when the medium precision is applied.

Try to include "precision highp float" in your shader. If your situation is the above one, it should fix the problem.

I hope to have helped in some way.

Maurizio